# jQuery: set dropdown options selected to the html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending the string containing html to the main div. This string contains the dropdown which is generated by some function which i cant modify. Now to this string containing the html with dropdown i would like to set option of the dropdown and then append the div

```
var stringHtml = "<div> <select>"+ someFunction() + "</select></div>";
jQuery('#mainDiv').append(stringHtml);
```

So someFunction() above helps to get the options for the select and then append the options

i would like to do somthing like this

```
jQuery(stringHtml).find("select option[value=\"" + sumeValue + "\"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and then append the html so that i get the required value selected

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are still inserting the string itself to the page. However what you should insert is the jQuery object created when you called `jQuery(stringHtml)`, because this is the one that was affected by your code. The results should look like:

```
var stringHtml = "<div> <select>"+ someFunction() + "</select></div>";
var html = jQuery(stringHtml); //save the whole string as an object
html.find("select").val(sumeValue); // alter the object
jQuery('#mainDiv').append(html); // insert the whole object to the page
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bLdM/2/). Note the slight optimization - there is no need to create this complex option selector, you can simply set the value of the select itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is a problem, The var html returns only the options that is why fiddle is working but if you add html to the stringHtml that is not getting displayed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6bLdM/1/ i have inserted Hello is the html which is not getting displayed

Comment: @user3273621, sorry, missed the point. It can be easily cured, please see the answer update. Fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/6bLdM/2/

Comment: @user3273621, just to let you know - accepting answers helps other users with similar problems, in case they googled your question. That way you are contributing to community of SO. This applies not only to this post, but to other your posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(stringHtml).find("select option[value='" + sumeValue + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: NO i tried that but not working. sets only the default value. I need solution that generates the stringHtml with applying the selected dropdown value

Comment: can you create fiddle??